# Excel VBA set active cell as range

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA I am selecting the first empty cell in a column using the following

```
Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

How can I set this currently active cell as a range for calling later in the macro.
I tried,

```
Dim Target as Range
Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Target = Cells(Application.ActiveCell)
```

My apologies if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the first empty cell at the end of the column then this is the slight variation required.  I would counsel against using the variable name `Target` because this is also a VBA keyword.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).offset(1,0)
MsgBox rng.Address
```

Comment: Good shout on the `Target` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select the cell first and as you're assigning an object, you need to use `Set` like so:

```
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Dim Target as Range
Set Target = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```